# Why does NSURLConnection redirect to itself?

Tags: ios, nsurlconnection

I'm trying to handle redirections in NSURLConnection. For my purpose, I want to record the redirection for later use and continue downloading the remainder of a page. To test, I tried to read http://www.google.com. Here's the code to handle the redirect:

```
- (NSURLRequest *) connection: (NSURLConnection *) connection
              willSendRequest: (NSURLRequest *) request
             redirectResponse: (NSURLResponse *) redirectResponse
{
    NSURL *url1 = [request URL];
    NSURL *url2 = [redirectResponse URL];
    if ([request URL] != nil)
        self.redirect = [request URL];
    return request;
}

- (void) connection: (NSURLConnection *) theConnection didReceiveResponse: (NSURLResponse *) response {
    NSURL *url1 = [response URL];
    int foo = 0;
}
```

Setting a breakpoint in these methods, I found that the redirection was directed to

http://www.google.com/

Specifically, in `connection:willSendRequest:redirectResponse:`, `url1` is set to http://www.google.com/, and `url2` is nil. In `connection:didReceiveResponse:`, `url1` is also http://www.google.com/.

OK, fine. Add the slash. But if I then open a new NSURLConnection using the URL with the trailing slash, I get the same thing back.

Why is the redirected URL the same as the original URL passed to NSURLConnection?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are seeing the first time the function is hit and there is no redirect yet. So if you did have a redirect you would see this hit on the original url and then hit a second time on the redirect. For your purposes you may want to store the URL when the request is started to check against to not do any action when it hasn't redirected yet.

Comment: I thought of that, but the method was never called a second time. (The breakpoint I set in these methods was never hit a second time.)