# Why does NSURLConnection stop sending data if you return nil from connection:willSendRequest:redirectResponse:

Tags: ios, nsurlconnection

I'm implementing a redirection handler for NSURLConnection. For my purpose, I don't actually want to do the redirection, I want to load the entire page and remember the redirection for later use. In the documentation for NSURLConnectionDataDelegate's connection:willSendRequest:redirectResponse: method, I find this:

> The actual URL request to use in light of the redirection response.
>   The delegate may return request unmodified to allow the redirect,
>   return a new request, or return nil to reject the redirect and
>   continue processing the connection.

I tried this code:

```
- (NSURLRequest *) connection: (NSURLConnection *) connection
              willSendRequest: (NSURLRequest *) request
             redirectResponse: (NSURLResponse *) redirectResponse
{
    NSURL *url1 = [request URL];
    NSURL *url2 = [redirectResponse URL];
    if ([request URL] != nil)
        self.redirect = [request URL];
    return nil;
}

- (void) connection: (NSURLConnection *) theConnection didReceiveResponse: (NSURLResponse *) response {
    NSURL *url1 = [response URL];
    int foo = 0;
}
```

The program never called `connection:didReceiveData:`, `connection:didFailWithError:` or `connectionDidFinishLoading:`. Returning `request` instead of `nil`, the program loaded the page normally. (The URL for the redirect was the original URL, but that's [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13755262/why-does-nsurlconnection-redirect-to-itself). If they are related, please kill two birds and answer that one, too.)

Is something else required to properly allow NSURLConnection to continue to process a file after a redirection attempt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An HTTP Redirect response is the end of the current connection most of the time. If your first connection ends with a redirect and you deny processing the redirect, there is nothing more to do.